# AlarmManager doesn't works properly

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I programatically set fire AlarmManager every 10 seconds,
This code works on all devices except the one I relly need.

On this device it calls every 60 seconds

Question: is there any limitation/configuration settings ?

```
alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 10000, alarmIntent);
```

Comment: If you need an interval that short, you shouldn't be using `AlarmManager`. And, yes, newer Android versions will force a minimum interval of 60 seconds.

Comment: thanks! I have root for this device, may I change this minimum ?

Comment: If you need such short interval, just use the `ScheduledExecutorService`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Handler` or `Executors` or `TimerTask`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html
newer android OS versions will mess up with your intervals. If you need exact timing you should use SetWindow or SetExact